# Specialty Beers at Local Markets

Tags: taste, specialty-beers, flavor

so I am trying to find some pretty nice beers, beer like a Delirium Tremens, to try. Does anyone have any recommendations on some nice beer that isn't insanely hard to find. Money is not really the issue, it's just I do not want to go looking at several specialty alcohol stores for one type of beer.

I live in North Carolina, near the triad area.

Comment: Where do you live?  There may be local breweries that make beers in that style but we need to know where you are to suggest any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is very broad and subjective, but I would recommend anything by [Allagash](http://www.allagash.com/beer/), especially [Tiarna](http://www.allagash.com/beer/limited-edition/tiarna) (outstanding), [Mischief](http://thebruery.com/beers/mischief.html) and [Saison Rue](http://thebruery.com/beers/saisonrue.html) by The Bruery, [Inferno](http://lostabbey.com/beer/inferno-ale/) by Lost Abbey, as well as widely available Belgian classics like Chimay, Duvel, Rochefort, Leffe, Kwak.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with the beers that are brewed closest to you. Although transportation and supply chain storage has greatly improved, beer is always best when you are closest to the source.

The North Carolina Brewers Guild will be a great resource for you to find beers in your area.

http://www.ncbeer.org

Belgian style beers, like the Delirium Tremens are growing in popularity very quickly. You should have no trouble finding some in your local area.

This might be a good place to start.

http://www.newbelgium.com/community/ashevillebrewery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is really incomplete since you haven't given us your locale.  But Tremens is a Belgian Golden Strong ale, so you could find similar flavors in anything with a description like "Belgian Gold", "Belgian Strong", "Belgian Pale", "Tripel", "Blonde" (Except American Blonde).

For well-known brands you'd be looking for something like... Duvel, Piraat, Hades (Great Divide), St. Bernardus Tripel, Chimay, Westmalle, Leffe Blonde, La Trappe Blonde, a few of the beers by Unibroue...

Answer (score 0):

You should try the famous smoke beer "Schlenkerla". Maybe you can find it in North Carolina: http://www.schlenkerla.de/verkauf/haendlerint/retailer-us.html